# > /dev/tty - What is the purpose of this command?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

This is in one of the rc scripts in Red Hat and I want to understand the purpose of > /dev/tty[n]

```
 last=0
 for i in `LC_ALL=C grep '^[0-9].*respawn:/sbin/mingetty' /etc/inittab | sed 's/^.* tty\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/g'`; do    
 > /dev/tty$i
 last=$i
```

To simplify the question for those having trouble understanding the script, what does the following code do exactly?  (it seems to send a null value to /dev/tty but why?)

```
> /dev/tty1
> /dev/tty2
```

Comment: I understand all of the rest of it, but I want to know only about the 3rd line.

Comment: Which rc script?

Comment: Are you sure you got the spacing correct in the sed bit?  This looks wrong, there appears to be spaces where there shouldn't be.  `'s/^.* tty\     ([0-  9][0-9]*\).*/\1/g`.

Comment: The formatting got screwy when I copied it here, I fixed the spacing.  This is the rc.sysinit script.  Anyone know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It outputs text to Linux virtual console N (Ctrl_Alt_n). In snippet you've quoted this would redirect output to every Linux Virtual Console supposed to have `mingetty` run on.

**UPD.:**

> (it seems to send a null value to /dev/tty but why?)

This might have a purpose of virtual consoles initialization — [man 4 console](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console):

> Before kernel version 1.1.54 the number of virtual consoles was compiled into the kernel (in tty.h: #define NR_CONSOLES 8) and could be changed by editing and recompiling. **Since version 1.1.54 virtual consoles are created on the fly, as soon as they are needed.**

— so, yep, it looks like on-demand creation.